# Using split method on strings through regular expressions by punctuation and whitespace but avoiding splitting words like wasn't to wasn and t

Tags: java, string, split

I try to split this sentence:
`use will effect the Project's reputation, your right to copy and`

to the words:`use` `will` `effect` `the` `Project's` `reputation` `your` `right` `to` `copy` `and`

I'm using `line.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s\\p{Digit}]+")`
but it's splitting the word `Project's` to `Project` `s`.

I try to subtract `'` like this :  `line.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s\\p{Digit}]+&&[^']")` but it is not working.

Also, I need to split words that start/end with `'` character. 
Is there a way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: The `&&[^']` needs to be *inside* the character class: `"[\\p{Punct}\\s\\p{Digit}&&[^']]+"`

Comment: Thanks.
it's working but I want to avoid splitting only words with `'` not in the first/last character.
It fixed the problem of words like: `Project's ` but words that start with `'` 
are still a problem.

There is any solution using only split?

Comment: `"(?:[\\p{Punct}\\s\\p{Digit}&&[^']]|(?<!\\p{Alpha})'|'(?!\\p{Alpha}))+"`

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Can you explain me your regex?

This : `[\\p{Punct}\\s\\p{Digit}&&[^']]` I understand, but use of Special constructs it's not clear. 

Thanks.

Comment: [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/5221149): `|` means OR. `(?<!\\p{Alpha})'` means a `'` not preceded by a letter. `'(?!\\p‌​{Alpha})` means `'` not followed by a letter. `(?:xxx)+` means one or more of `xxx`. Or see [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ie8CLq/1).

Comment: Thanks!!

I see that the split method keeps this word `""`
if I do this:
`String check = null;
 check = "";    
 for (String word : check.split("(?:[\\p{Punct}\\s\\p{Digit}&&[^']]|(?<!\\p{Alpha})'|'(?!\\p{Alpha}))+"))
 {
   if(word.equals(""))
 System.out.println("null");`

It's prints `null` 

What I need to add to the regex to avoid the `""` ?

Thanks?

Comment: It's how [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) works: *If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string.* An empty string doesn't contain any special characters, so result is `{ "" }`. Also note that if input is `"!x!"`, result is `{ "", "x" }`, but input `"!"` gives `{}`. In short, it's up to you to ignore the first value in the result if it is empty.